# tar extract all files from folder inside archive

Tags: linux, extract, archive, tar

Let's say I have a tar archive with the following structure:

> "NAME/FOLDER/FILES"

e.g.

```
tarfolder.tar.gz/test123/[file1,file2,filex]
```

Now I wan't to extract all files from the folder test123 without extracting the "test123" folder itself. What's the command to do so?

Comment: Sorry, can you clear a little what is the structure that you have. Is `tarfolder.tar.gz` your original tar file?

Comment: tarfolder.tar.gz --> contains a folder: test123 --> folder test123 contains a lot of files

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
tar -zxfv tarfolder.tar.gz test123/ --strip-components=1
```

Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use the tar zxvf option, like this:

```
tar -zxvf tarfolder.tar.gz test123/file1
```

Comment: okay but I want to extract all files and wildcards are not allowed.

Comment: you can do a for loop

Comment: what if all files are named different?